# Strip tags in dynamic table

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to remove tags from the status feed on my website to stop html/php/javascript injection using the strip_tags() php command. I'm using a dynamic table and this is my code, except it doesn't work.`<?php echo strip_tags($row_chat['content'];, '') ?>` What's going wrong?

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($orw_chat["content"])`  (Take the output from the source code)?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work. What are you giving it? What does it return? You don't need to pass an empty string to strip_tags to strip everything.

Comment: I've just used <marquee>Hello</marquee> as a post and it scrolls. I don't want it or any other html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row_chat['content']); ?>
```

Misplaced ";".

Start reading the documentation
https://php.net/strip_tags